# How to show both Navigation Bar and Tool Bar on iPhone?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have an existing app that on iOS 5 that showed tool bar and navigation bar at once. Now in iOS 7 it shows one or another.
Are you guys aware of something that I should do in other to show both as bars at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Seems like

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.hidden = NO;
```

doesn't work all the time.